# latency Issue with Apache httpd request

Tags: apache, webserver, httpd.conf, openshift-4

We are using deployed a pod of Apache Webserver on OCP4. Currently we are facing latency issue in this. When request is triggered from browser to webserver and from webserver to appserver. we saw Webserver hold this request in one of its module. This has been further investigated (through Dynatrace logs) and found there is some delay of request processing from `Aggregated Apache hooks calls` to handle (mod_lua) of Apache server. I can't paste logs here due to sensitivity nature. but can demonstrate by an example: -

`Web request` (/App_version/request)     Elapsed type

`Apache`
`Aggregated Apache hooks calls`           +79ms

`handler (mod_lua)`                                  +30s

the self execution time is for `Aggregated Apache hooks calls` is very less but request movement from hooks call to handle taking almost 30secs. 
 we are struggling with this issue last one week. it happening only on prodution environment but for non-prod with same config working fine. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does your lua handler do and how does it relate to your appserver? How long does your appserver take to respond?

Comment: Do you have the same load on "non-prod" prod server? I think your first target should be to able to reproduce the issue on the "non-prod". Could it be possible to use the non-prod as live temporary?